# samba share error with file of which name includes "@"

Tags: samba

- List item

I use Windows to copy a file to a samba shares (Linux)

[https://i.imgur.com/tN45IrF.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjdw7.png)

But :

#0 name special**@**chars.html leads to error "The system cannot find the file specified"

#0 name special_chars.html : no errors

漢語.txt : no errors

What happens ? Why the ansii letter "@" causes error ?

Thanks

**Update** :

```
root@nas:~# testparm -sv | grep mangled
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed by GnuTLS (e.g. NTLM as a compatibility fallback)

WARNING: some services use vfs_fruit, others don't. Mounting them in conjunction on OS X clients results in undefined behaviour.

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

    mangled names = no
    mangled names = illegal
    mangled names = illegal
    mangled names = illegal

root@nas: smbd -V
Version 4.17.12-Debian
```

Update: I fixed it. mangled nails it. Thanks all

Comment: I just added a file with an @ in it and it was OK. Please edit your original post with the output of the following commands: `smbd -V` and `testparm -sv | grep mangled`

Comment: @Morbius1 could you share your smb.conf file ?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/tN45IrF.png

Comment: I just fixed it. Thanks @Morbius1